# How to make an auto posting bot for Telegram in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to make a simple bot for a channel in Telegram that an a specific interval of time send a message.
I only read about other bot that makes this...

Someone knows something more?

Comment: Can you specify an technical problem? Wellcome to stackoverflow! Please read How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: for example I want to send a message every hour in a telegram channel, how can I make this? (without input from users)

Comment: @m-t In order to be able to do so, you will have first to:
     Create a Telegram public channel
     Create a Telegram BOT via BotFather
    Set the bot as administrator in your channel

Provided that you did the above, now you can send a message to your channel by issuing and HTTP GET request to the Telegram BOT API at the following URL: api.telegram.org/bot[BOT_API_KEY]/sendMessage?chat_id=[MY_CHANNEL_NAME]&text=[MY_MESSAGE_TEXT]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **threads**.

This way your main thread *(the one that contains the main program)* keeps running.
And the second thread with a timer posts at regular intervals to you chosen messages.

This is a **small example** as **I don't have your own code on which to base my answers.**

```
import threading
import time
import telebot

def message_timer():
     # Waiting time 15 minutes
     time.sleep(60 * 15)
     bot.send_message(user_id, "Message")


# Do some stuff...

x = threading.Thread(target = message_timer)
x.start()

# Do some stuff ...
```